# Error running python script in RStudio and shiny app using reticulate

Tags: python, r, shiny, reticulate

I have a python script in which I have defined a function using the "adtk" package. Using reticulate, I call my function from R and apply it on some data. This totally works with no error. However, when I try to do the exact same thing but in a shiny app, it gives me the following error: **module adtk has no attribute transformer**!

RStudio code piece:

```
library(reticulate)
use_condaenv('my_conda_env')
source_python("my_python_script.py")
```

Python script:

```
import adtk

def my_func():
  adtk.transformer.DoubleRollingAggregate()
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like running your code locally could be unintentionally using your system Python (and its adtk package) rather than using your conda environment, which may be missing adtk and/or some of its modules.

When you run `library(reticulate)`, the reticulate package will try to initialize its best-guess version of Python, which may not be the version that you intend to use. Since Python has already been initialized for your session, running `use_condaenv('my_conda_env')` afterwards will likely be ignored. (You can test this by trying to run `use_condaenv('my_conda_env', required = TRUE)` instead to see if you get an error similar to: `The requested version of Python (<conda env python path>) cannot be used, as another version of Python (<system python path>) has already been initialized.`)

To force your code to run in your conda environment, restart your R session and run `reticulate::use_condaenv('my_conda_env', required = TRUE)`. Confirm that the environment is being used by running `reticulate::py_config()`.

You can double check that the correct version of adtk is installed in your conda env by [viewing the installed packages](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#viewing-a-list-of-installed-packages). Finally, make sure that conda is supported on the system that you're running your Shiny app ([conda isn't currently supported on shinyapps.io](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-use-conda-environment-in-shinyapps-io/18630), for example, but you could use virtualenv instead.)

Comment: Thanks @Rani for the response.You are indeed right. But, I have tried your suggestion and still receives the same error. Actually, importing the `transformer` sub-package and the `DoubleRollingAggregate` in the python script as `import adtk.transormer.DoubleRollingAggregate`, works well! The error was for when I only did `import adtk` in the python script. In the latter case, I added `import("adtk.transformer")` in the app script in R, and the error was gone. I think importing only `adtk` doesn't make its sub-packages available in the global namespace or in the `sys.modules`!